# Error opening zip file created using java and no size for the file

Tags: java, android, zip

I have a problem with my zip file created with JAVA, i losted two days on this problem.

My Zip File is save on my external storage of my device, but the size of the file is 0 octet and i can't open this file(error say: Archive damaged or unknown format (see the image below).

This is strange because i can read and load zip file data on my app without problem.[image: zip file with 0 octet size and the error message]

This is how i create my zip file

```
File zipFile = new File(dir, activity.fileName + AppConstant.ZIP_EXTN);
        FilesUtils.refreshFile(activity, zipFile);

        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile),102400));
        try
        {
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(AppConstant.SESSION_FILENAME));
            try
            {
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(zos);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(session);
                objectOutputStream.flush();

            } finally
            {
                zos.closeEntry();
            }

            for (Releve r : listReleve) 
            {
                for (String photoPath : r.getListPathPhoto()) 
                {
                    File file = new File(photoPath);
                    if(file.exists()){
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(AppConstant.PATH_TO_PHOTO_ZIP_FOLDER+file.getName());
                        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                        FilesUtils.copyStream(fis,zos);
                        fis.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally{
            zos.close();
        }
```

And this is how i read zip file.

```
private Session readFromZipExternalStorage(File sessionZip) throws IOException
    {
        Session sessionToReturn = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;

        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(sessionZip));
        try
        {
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            while(ze!=null)
            {
                if(ze.getName().endsWith(AppConstant.SESSION_EXTN))
                {
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(zis);
                    try {
                        sessionToReturn = (Session) in.readObject();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            }
        }finally {
            in.close();
            zis.close();
        }
        return sessionToReturn;
    }
```

and here you have the logcat warning.

```
07-09 14:58:29.182: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.checkClosed(ZipInputStream.java:368)
07-09 14:58:29.182: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:125)
07-09 14:58:29.182: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:212)
07-09 14:58:29.182: W/System.err(9735):     at com.app.rir.activity.gestionsession.HelperbuildTab.readFromZipExternalStorage(HelperConstructionTableau.java:93)
07-09 14:58:29.182: W/System.err(9735):     at com.app.rir.activity.gestionsession.HelperBuildTab.buildTabBody(HelperConstructionTableau.java:49)
07-09 14:58:29.182: W/System.err(9735):     at com.app.rir.activity.gestionsession.ManageSessionActivity.onResume(ManageSessionActivity.java:80)

07-09 14:58:24.925: W/System.err(9735): java.io.IOException: Stream is closed
07-09 14:58:24.936: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.checkOpen(ZipOutputStream.java:427)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:132)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at com.app.rir.activity.principale.HelperSauvegardeSession.saveSession(HelperSauvegardeSession.java:98)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at com.app.rir.activity.principale.HelperSauvegardeSession.doInBackground(HelperSauvegardeSession.java:50)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at com.app.rir.activity.principale.HelperSauvegardeSession.doInBackground(HelperSauvegardeSession.java:1)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-09 14:58:24.940: W/System.err(9735):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-09 14:58:24.941: W/System.err(9735):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**EDIT**

As dotvav say, i try `objectOutputStream.close()`, just after the flush, now the file have a size and i can open the zip on windows, but image are not add in the zip file.

I debbug and i found, i don't pass in double loop `for (Releve r : listReleve)`  the execution stop after the first `finally` and go to the last finally with same warning like above.

Comment: You get an error because your zip file is empty. The problem must be in the zip file creation part. I suggest you try simpler file creations first. And possibly call `objectOutputStream.close()`.

Comment: Ok, i will try to simpler file creations. But if the zip file is empty why i can read the content in my app and load the information ?